# Detecting very small magnetic movements

Tags: sensor, magnetics

I am looking for techniques and methods to detect very small linear magnetic movement caused by a bar magnet. Imagine a bar magnet that can produce yaw and pitch but with extremely low frequency and within few degrees outlined below. I have ability to locate this device conveniently far or close.

My design parameters are as follows:

Yaw angle can change -4 to +4 degrees
Pitch angle can change -1 to +1 degrees
Temp: 32F to 110F
Variation will happen over period of hours.

I have no sense of strength of magnet involved. However, I can place sensing device far or close as required.

I'm looking for suggestions to help me accomplish this task.

Comment: Check out TIs inductance to digital converters

Comment: Check out [the policy on what's on-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead!

Comment: So this is not a "buying recommendation"?

Comment: WHere are your specs including geometry rotation range etc  THe best question is a list of all important design criteria incl. temperature stability, resolution drift etc etc But it sounds like you need an armature of multiple coils to detect pole position.  A rotary encoder might be smarter. But only you know the interface specs.

Comment: @pipe, buying recommendation is completely different from part recommendation.

Comment: @Mandar Are you downvoting people's answers? If you are, could give them an explanation of why you're doing so?

Comment: @KingDuken, No, I am not.

Comment: It is rude to downvote without expressing your opinions. ( whoever you are)

Comment: There I upvoted and I'll keep it there until the person who downvoted is able to explain themselves.

Comment: I guess its just not 1, there are multiple rude people...

Comment: The explicit text from the close-vote reason reads "Questions seeking **recommendations for specific products** or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete" - so how are "part recommendations" not off-topic?

Comment: @KingDuken First of all, it's generally recommended _not_ to explain downvotes after someone asks for them. It just tends to create long comment threads and worst case lead to retaliation. Second, while the voting privilege is to be used as you see fit, the voting system works best if you vote according to the usefulness of a post, not as some kind of "compensation". Since you get 10 rep for an upvote but -2 for a downvote you're not balancing anything.

Comment: Perhaps you could rephrase your question to ask what methods (versus specific parts) are available to sense small angle changes.  Answers to this question would be more generally useful.

Comment: @KingDuken I haven't downvoted, but I'll give a plausible explanation for why some people have: The two existing answers are poor for the same reason the question is poor: they violate the goal of this site (and SE in general) which is to provide information that is useful to others and does not become obsolete. In my view, providing specific product recommendations is to encourage others to ask for product recommendations. One of the answers is better, at least it describes what the products are and how to use any similar products to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @pipe and Kevin, Good points :) thanks for the reminders

Comment: Question is already reworded. I don't understand why its on hold still.

Comment: @Mandar - Re-opening a closed question is no more automatic than closing it was in the first place. It needs 5 re-open votes or direct intervention by a mod.

Comment: You detect magnetic fields with a magnetometer, to determine the sensitivity of magnetometer you will need to delve into electromagnetic theory.

Answer (score 1):

Try a part like this
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/allegro-microsystems-llc/A1335LLETR-DD-T/620-1767-1-ND/5774399
Can sense rotary position when installed at the end of a shaft and rotated above the chip.

> The A1335 incorporates a Hall sensor IC that measures the direction
>   of the magnetic field vector through 360° in the x-y plane
>   (parallel to the branded face of the device). The A1335 computes
>   the angle based on the actual physical reading, as well as any
>   internal parameters that have been set by the user. The end user
>   can configure the output dynamic range, output scaling, and
>   filtering.

Answer (score 1):

There are a broad range of magnetic sensors, usually labelled as magnetic encoders.

One example supplier is AMS, who have both SPI and I2C sensors with resolutions down to fractions of a degree. Look on [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/sensors-transducers/encoders/507?k=AMS%20magnetic%20sensor) for the variants.
I've used many of the AS5600 for CNC control pendants and they work well with only a single magnetic pole pair.

There are variants such the TI [TIDA-00480](http://www.ti.com/tool/tida-00480) which require a multipole magnet. These typically have much lower resolution.

You could of course (you want to measure shaft rotation) use a simple optical shaft encoder with a home position indicator. Since you obviously have and MCU, using this solution might be the least engineering effort.

Comment: Thanks you. I have edited question to specify more details about amount of movement I want to detect. AS5600 looks interesting. If you have any experience dealing with hysteresis with these parts, I would love to her about it.